# Как передать параметры Save_param методу (функции) S1 and 10?

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, параметры

```
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):                        
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)            
    self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(Save_param("S1",'10'))

 def Save_param(str,value):
    with open('config.json','r') as f:
        config=json.load(f)
    config[str]=value
    with open('config.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(config,f)
```

---

**Error**:

> File "/home/pi/python/main.py", line 100, in `__init__`
> self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(Save_param('S1','10'))
> TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'

Как передать параметры  **`S1`** and **`10`** ?

В итоге хочу сделать так:

```
self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(Save_param("S1",self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.value()))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: сделайте функцию save_param методом класса, а не внешней функцией.

Comment: спасибо за совет, это не помогает,

Answer (score 0):

спасибо за просторы интернета

```
self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(lambda:Save_param("S1",self.ui.doubleSpinBox_S1.value()))
```

вот так работает

```
lamda: $)
```

Answer (score 0):

я не уверен что правильно понял вас, но попробуйте

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.doubleSpinBox_S1 = QSpinBox()
        self.doubleSpinBox_S1.setRange(1, 42)
        self.doubleSpinBox_S1.setValue(12)  

#        self.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(Save_param("S1",'10'))        
        self.doubleSpinBox_S1.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value, s1="S1": self.save_param(value, s1))

        self.sizeLabel = QLabel(
            "Значениe из SpinBoxt: <b style='color: blue;'> 12 </b>")

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.sizeLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.doubleSpinBox_S1)

    def save_param(self, value, s_param):
        self.sizeLabel.setText(
            f"Значениe из SpinBoxt: <b style='color: blue;'> {value} </b>; "
            f"s_param: `<b style='color: blue;'> {s_param} </b>`"
        )
        '''
        with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
            config=json.load(f)
            
        config[s_param]=value
        
        with open('config.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(config, f)
        '''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо дружище!!!!

Comment: @ДмитрийСергеев пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour